# facebook app action grammar

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a Facebook app to make calls. Well, I'm still having trouble getting the action verified.

I got this message when I tried to submit it for approval:

[image: approval status]

The action grammar is as follows:

[image: action grammar]

I couldn't find the mistake in the grammar I specified. I read their documentation. I still couldn't figure it out.

Can anyone please advice what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What are your action and object called?

Comment: @CBroe .. My action is Made and the object is call. Thanx.

Comment: Try calling your action “make” (present tense) instead of “made”.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your imperative tense is too long.

Change `'make free calls using'` to `'call using'`